# Istio Egress 1.14 wildcard configuration for arbitrary domains

Tags: istio, egress

in older versions of Istio, when you wanted to use an egress gateway to allow the communication with a arbitrary domains, you could use wildcards with a SNI proxy as it's explained in https://istio.io/v1.13/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/wildcard-egress-hosts/#setup-egress-gateway-with-sni-proxy

I don't see how to do it in version 1.14. Any help?

Regards.